A relation coming both transitive and not transitive

A relation $R$ is defined as $(x,y)\in R \implies x^y=y^x$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{I}-\{0\}$, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of integers. Find whether the relation $R$ is transitive or not.

Let $x^y=y^x$ and $y^z=z^y$
We have to prove that $x^z=z^x$
Now, $y\ln x=x \ln y$ and $z\ln y=y \ln z$
$\implies y \ln x=\frac{y\ln z}{z}\cdot x$ or $z \ln x=x \ln z$ or $x^z=z^x$
So it seems that this relation is transitive. Here's the catch, I can't find even one triplet where this transitive relation holds. And here's another proof which claims that the relation is not transitive.
Since $x^y=y^x$ we can say that $y=x^{\frac{y}{x}}$
$\implies (x^{\frac{y}{x}})^z=z^y$ or $x^{yz}=z^{xy}$
which says that it isn't transitive.
Which one is correct and why$?$
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Edited. Sorry for the typo.

I don't understand your second proof. Your former proof is correct. The reason you can't find any tuples where transitivity holds is because there are no tuples where $xRy$ and $yRz$ at all. You might say it is vacuously transitive. Every number greater than $1$ has another number it is paired with, which is the only number it is related to besides itself. Numbers $\le 1$ are only related to themselves. So nothing is related to two different numbers other than itself.

Wait my comment was if the relation was defined on the positive reals. For the positive integers, $4$ and $2$ are the only two distinct numbers related to each other. Again making it vacuously transitive.

I don’t think the second proof is valid because the implication is not correct. It should either say $z^y$ or $z^{x^{\frac{y}{x}}}$ on the RHS.

So, the biggest underlying problem here is that the solutions to the equation $x^y = y^x$ are only at $x=y \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ne 0}$ and $(x,y) = (2,4)$ and $(x,y) = (4,2)$. That is,
$$
R = \{(2,4),(4,2)\} \cup \{(n,n) \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ne 0}\}
$$
So ultimately, there is no nontrivial pairing $(x,y),(y,z) \in R$ to work with. If $y \in \{2,4\}$, then you have pairs of the type
$$
(x,2),(2,z)
$$
let's say. But then $x,z \in \{2,4\}$, and all possible pairs $(x,z)$ from that set work, so no violations can occur there. It's similar for $y=4$. And if $y$ is anything else, then $x$ and $z$ are forced to share the same value as $y$ to have $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ in $R$ in the first place.
So ultimately, yes, the relation is transitive.
Solving $x^y=y^x$ is ultimately a well-known problem, c.f. some past discussion on MSE here or Wikipedia here.

With your first proof, I take umbrage with the use of the logarithm since that implicitly assumes your numbers are positive; $\ln(-1)$, for instance, is not well-defined in the reals.
The second proof sketches me out for similar reasons, by making assumptions on exponent laws and how they work for negative numbers. (What if $y/x$ was a fraction, for instance?) I don't think this proof arrived at a convincing enough conclusion to determine (non)transitivity either.
